Open barcode reader application from web page on IOS devices
I have a web page, on android devices when you press a button it gives you the option to read a barcode using an application and then the result of the reading is returned to the web page.
For example on android this application works very well to read barcodes: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teacapps.barcodescanner&hl=en_US
JavaScript code
function redirect_to_scanner() {
  let current_url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
  let new_url     = "zxing://scan/?ret=" 
                  + encodeURIComponent(current_url 
                  + "?barcode={CODE}");
  window.location.href = new_url;
}

This coding works perfectly on android devices but not on ios devices, in that case a message appears “An error occurred can not open the application”
Is there any other URI that I can use and that works on ios devices? or any way to make it work on ios devices?
The other option would be to open a barcode reader inside the web page written in JavaScript like quagga js but I would like to avoid this option because it does not work very well to read 20 digit barcodes. Any recommendation?
